# Prove that the space $(C [a, b], \|\cdot\|_1)$ is not a Banach space.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> How can I prove that the space $(C [a, b], \|\cdot\|_1)$ is not a Banach space?
>   If we are working with  $\|f\|_1=\int_0^1|f(t)|$ on the space of all 
>    real continuous functions in the $[a,b]$ interval. 
>   Is there a way to prove that $(C [a, b], \|\cdot\|_1)$ is not complete?

I think it is easier if I took a sequence of functions in $[0,1]$ and prove that it is a Cauchy sequence that converges to a discontinuous function hence get a contradiction. But I don´t know how to make it in general ( for the $[a,b]$ interval)

This is my first idea.

$f_n: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R},\text{ given by }f_n(x)=  \ \begin{cases}
1  & \text{ $  x ≤ \frac{1}{2}$}\\[2ex]
\left(\cfrac{1}{2}n+1-nx\right) &\text{$\frac{1}{2} < x ≤ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n}$}  \\[2ex]
0 & \text{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n} < x $}
\end{cases}$

Comment: Your norm is not a norm.

Comment: Usually $\|f\|_{L^1} = ∫ |f|$. Or perhaps you are looking for $\|f\|_{L^2} = (∫ |f|^2)^{1/2}$?
But your idea seems correct, just compute the difference $\|f_n-f\|$ now

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413582/pointwise-convergence-not-enough-to-show-incompleteness-of-continous-functions-f?rq=1) answer your question?

Comment: Yes, now I am trying to think why $||f||_1=\int_0^1|f|^2$ is not a norm. But thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to correct the norm.

Once that's done, how about $f_n(x)=x^n$.  Then each $f_n$ is continuous, but the sequence converges to a discontinuous $f$.

Comment: It is in general $[a,b]$? Because for $[0,1]$ works. Thanks!

Comment: Good question @OscarWada.  The answer may be no.

Comment: I think this is not a good counter-example, because $f_n$ is convergent in $(C[0,1], \lVert . \rVert_1)$, and it's limit is zero.

Comment: @Botond isn't the limit $1$ at $1$?

Comment: Yes, the pointwise limit at $1$ is $1$. But we usually talk about "convergence in norm" on normed spaces, and $f_n$ converges to $0$ in norm, because $\lVert f_n-0\rVert = \int_0^1 |x^n| \mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{n+1} \to 0$.

Comment: Your example would be good if the norm were the sup-norm, because the uniform convergence and pointwise convergence is "closer to each other" than the $L^1$ convergence and pointwise convergence.

Comment: @Botond I thought it was a pointwise limit.  I thought the other way was the sup norm, $||•||_\infty$.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean? Sorry, my native language is not English.

Comment: @Botond thanks for straightening me out.

Comment: @Botond I think I see.  The norm is defined by an integral, and thus a set of measure zero doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, that's what happens here. But you can use your sequence to prove that the space $(C[0,1], \lVert . \rVert_1)$ is not complete, using Banach's linear homeomorphism theorem; it guarantees that a continuous, linear bijection between two Banach spaces is invertible. I did it with the $2$-norm not so long ago (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3646171/281471), and the argument is the same with the $1$-norm.

Comment: But that theorem is an "overkill", because it's one of the key theorems in functional analysis, and it requires the axiom of choice.

Comment: @Botond well, I can't delete, because the OP accepted my answer